# Multiple shopping carts and copy paste cart

Tags: shopping-cart, wishlist

I have a client spec where the client is acquiring for us to develop a store where there are possible to have multiple shopping carts and an user can "copy a cart"
Is this possible? Are there any extension for such thing?

BTW, they want to use a guest wish list that allows to add and share wish list without logging in, and of course add items to this same cart...and download pdf

Any hints on good extensions for achieving those advanced features?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for ajax / multi-cart 
this is free extension you can modify it according to you or make as per client requirment

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pascal-system-ajax-quick-cart-view-and-add.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what other features you're looking for but OroCommerce may be a viable option if you're looking to largely build a B2B site.